# remove all of a class in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

In `outer` div   I want to remove all the classes `testClass`  but this is not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/TAcZJ/

jquery

```
$('#outer').removeClass('testClass');
```

html

```
 <span class="testClass">d</span>
 <span class="testClass">d</span>
 <span class="testClass">d</span>
 <span class="testClass">d</span>

<div id="outer">
    <span class="testClass">d</span>
    <span class="testClass">d</span>
    <span class="c">d</span>
    <span class="testClass">d</span>
    <span class="testClass">d</span>
    <span class="testClass">d</span>
    <span class="c">d</span>
    <span class="testClass">d</span>
    <span class="testClass">d</span>
    <span class="testClass">d</span>
</div>
```

css

```
.testClass{color:red;}

.c{ color:blue;}
```

Comment: `$('.testClass', '#outer').removeClass('testClass')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#outer > .testClass').removeClass('testClass');
```

You're currently selecting only the wrapper div, not the children spans with the class. I would argue against the other answers, since they are selecting more elements than necessary.

Answer (score 6):

### **Approach 1**

```
$('#outer > .testClass').removeClass('testClass');('testClass');
```

### **Approach 2**

```
$('#outer').find('span').removeClass('testClass');
```

### **Approach 3**

```
$('#outer').children('span').removeClass
```

### **Approach 4**

```
$('#outer').children().removeClass('testClass');
```

### **Approach 5**

```
jQuery.grep($('#outer > .testClass'), function (data) {
        $(data).removeClass('testClass');
});
```

### **Approach 6**

```
$.each($('#outer > .testClass'), function(index, data){
     $(data).removeClass('testClass');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
$('#outer').children().removeClass('testClass');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#outer span').removeAttr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#outer > span').removeClass('testClass');
```

or

```
  $('#outer  span').removeClass('testClass');
```

[**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/TAcZJ/1/)

Comment: @Hello-World check this once

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("outer").innerHTML = document.getElementById("outer").innerHTML.replace(/testClass/g, '');
```

Just use some VanilaJS ;-) should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#outer span').removeClass('testClass');
```

or

```
$('#outer .testClass').removeClass('testClass');
```

or

```
$('#outer').find('.testClass').removeClass('testClass');
```